# Add new email user in Dovecot

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, dovecot, imap, roundcube

I installed Dovecot 2.2.10 & Roundcube in Amazon Linux (apparently it's a CentOS variant).

If I want to add a new mailbox (e.g. `info@mydomain.com`) to IMAP, how do I add this mailbox? I read from Dovecot documentation, there are quite a lot different ways to do so, e.g. static userdb/ dynamic userdb/ add user via PAM, etc. Which method should I pick?

note: this user does not require to login to Linux; it's authorized to access mailbox via IMAP or Roundcube webmail.

Comment: You should use the method you used for the first email.  Go back to the documentation you followed to figure it out.

Comment: I don't even have the first email. As said, I just setup Dovecot.

Comment: My point still stands that you should refer to the guide you used to setup Dovecot as it will show you how to complete what you started.  Setting up a mail server is a complex task and it can not be answered in a single post here.

Comment: In the guide I followed, it suggested using `postfixadmin` which worked out pretty well to handle everything in a DB.  (Note that the best 3 guides I found were not functional as is and I had to solve certain issues myself.)

Comment: which "guide" you followed ?

Comment: I can not recommend them as they are far from perfect as I mentioned.  Why don't you go back to the one you followed?

Comment: The guides I followed didn't work. I tried PostfixAdmin and it can now create new mailboxes. However, it cannot be logged in via Roundcube. Anything I missed?

Comment: You didn't configure dovecot to use that authentication which will require additional packages.  You can look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin but as I said, there is no perfect guide.

Answer (score 2):

Raptor,

There are really two main ways of setting up mail boxes. The first is the default when the mailbox is associated with a unix/linux id. The second method is to create a service id in linux and use it to serve all email. The second one is the one you want and the setup is a little more complicated than the first. It appears that you have implemented the first way. The second method can be summerized as follows. I am assuming you are using postfix as your MTA

Update postfix config to use a database like mysql to hold email ids
Update postfix config to use dovecot for mail delivery
Create user accounts in mysql by sql command or GUI (recommended)
Update Dovecot config to use the postfix/mysql method
Update roundcube to use dovecot

I have these running on multiple mailservers and If you need help in setting this up, let me know and I will be glad to help

Unni (unni@theyjas.com)
Theyjas Systems

Comment: Thanks for the info. How do I config postfix to use MySQL as passwords DB & what will be the schema? How to set roundcube to use Dovecot ? Still confused.

Comment: Raptor, I have an rpm that would do all of these steps in one shot if you are interested. I am also creating a documentation for this. Let me know if you are interested in the rpm

Comment: Raptor, I have an rpm that would do all of these steps in one shot if you are interested. I am also creating a documentation for this. Let me know if you are interested in the rpm... Unni (unni@theyjas.com)